# Sorting ListBiew by Spinner in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, filter, android-listview, spinner

I have one `ListView` and one `Spinner`. The `Spinner` is situated at the right top of the layout. My `ListView` contains some names (eg. country names) and the spinner has some alphabets (a-z). Suppose if  I choose the letter `"f"` from the `Spinner`, my `ListView` must show the country names that  starts only with the letter `"f"` . I want to sort my `ListView` by values from the `Spinner`?

Comment: Do you use a custom adapter for the `ListView`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a Filter for your ListView. Everytime the [OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) of your Spinner gets called you need to filter the items. If you're not sure how to implement a filter in your ListView's adapter have a look at this: [Filtering ListView with custom (object) adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780289/filtering-listview-with-custom-object-adapter)

I guess there won't be any way around implementing an own ListAdapter (it's easy).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `getFilter()` method of the `ListView` adapter:

```
        String[] filterL = { "a", "b", "c" }; //etc
        //...

        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> aspin = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filterL); //the adapter for the Spinner
        aspin.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(aspin);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries); //the adapter for the list
        setListAdapter(aa); //set the adapter for the list(if you extend LisActivity) or call setAdapter on the ListView element
        //add the listener:
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            boolean status = false;

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                if (!status) {
                    status = true;
                    return;
                }

                aa.getFilter().filter(filterL[position]);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
```