# Android ListView: don't show all strings

Tags: android, string, listview

I show a listview from the following string:

```
String[] values = new String[] { test1, test2, test3 };
```

The variables:

```
private String test1 = "test";
private String test2 = "test";
private String test3 = "test3";
```

Now I don't want to show the strings that contain "test" in my listview.
Like this:

```
if (String == "test") {
*don't show in ListView*;}
```

And I want it to test all Strings at once if they contain "test"

How is it possible?

EDIT: Here the adapter code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Filter them out of the string array and create an `ArrayAdapter` using the filtered array.

Comment: Can we see some more of your code? Particularly your Adapter for the ListView.  One way of doing this would be to remove the strings that contain test from the adapter itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup...

```
if (values[i].equals("test")) // i being the iterator of your for-loop
```

OR

```
if (values[i].contains("test"))
```

contains is a slow(er) string function though.

You might want to use an ArrayList though... that way you can just add all those objects to the array list, then iterate through it... and remove them as you go...

```
// Do something to add all items to your array list
...
// Iterate through the list, removing what doesn't need to be there
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
    if (arrayList.get(i).contains("test"))
        arrayList.remove(i);
}
```

...Then set 'arrayList' (or whatever you've called it) as the string list for your adapter. If you use the same constructor it'll look like this...

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arrayList.toArray());
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question of how to filter certain values out of his ListView.

Comment: Edited to help him filter things out. It's about as straight-forward as it's possibly going to get now...

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a filter on your ListView.  Look at these examples:

(Simple iterating) http://androidsearchfilterlistview.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-custom-list-view-filter.html
(getFilter()) [Filtering ListView with custom (object) adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780289/filtering-listview-with-custom-object-adapter)

Like others have posted, you compare String objects using `.equals()`, but if you are trying to only display certain items in your `ListView` you should use the `getFilter()` method like described in the link I posted.

edit: I found you a nice SO example.

Answer (score 1):

all the time, if you want compare 2 strings use the `equals` methode

[read this about The equals() method](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week4/37.html)