# Listfilter using Simplecursoradapter

Tags: android

I want to filter my list when user types something into the text box.

but nothing happens when trying to type into textbox.

I saw many topics but could realize what is wrong.

I know this question is asked many times, but i could solve it.

Here is my code:

```
public class Find extends ListActivity {

private EditText filterText = null;
DBHandler db=new DBHandler(this);
ListView myList;
String[] items = new String[10];
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=null;
int test = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_search);
    filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbox);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);


Cursor cursor=db.getEvents();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String[] from = {"_id","full_name"};
    int[] to = { R.id.name_entry, R.id.number_entry};
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_find, cursor, from, to);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

My textwatcher method:

```
    private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need a few extra things to have filtering working with a SimpleCursorAdapter. First you need to identify the [string conversion column](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#setStringConversionColumn%28int%29) for your adapter and second you need to implement a [FilterQueryProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FilterQueryProvider.html) and add it to your adapter through the setFilterQueryProvider method call.

Here's a simple example of a FilterQueryProvider implementation:

```
mAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
   @Override
   public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) { 
      if (constraint == null) {
         // contract: if constraint is null, return the same as before
     return mAdapter.getCursor();
      } else {
         //TODO: run your query here... 
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at these?

[Filtering ListView with custom (object) adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780289/filtering-listview-with-custom-object-adapter)
<- on a textview.. user starts typing text..

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/
<- shows text field at the top.. and you type inside it...

Answer (score 0):

I have my custom method to achieve filteration with two set of `ArrayList`. (you can modifty it as per your need.)

1) Searching ArrayList
2) Main ArrayList

First method is for setting your search array with the value same as your main array.

```
public void setarray() {


        for (int j = 0; j < MainArray.size(); j++) {

            SearchArray.add(MainArray.get(j));
        }
    }
```

Second method is for displaying your ListView with your array.

```
public void displaylist() {

        myCustomArrayAdaptor adapter = new myCustomArrayAdaptor(this,
                R.layout.myLayOut, SearchArray);

        mylistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);

        mylistView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

Third Method to filter your ListView

```
public void setsearcharray(CharSequence searchstr) {

//clear your array before adding the new value in it

        SearchArray.clear();

        int len1 = searchstr.length();

// if your search text length is zero then transfer all your main array data to search array.
        if (len1 == 0) {

            for (int j = 0; j < MainArray.size(); j++) {

                SearchArray.add(MainArray.get(j));
            }

// then display your listview with your search array value.
            displaylist();
        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < MainArray.size(); j++) {

                String strvalue = MainArray.get(j);

                int length = searchstr.length();

//if your search text length is smaller then the value that is in your array

                if (strvalue.length() >= length) {
                    String substr = strvalue.substring(0, length);

                    if (substr.equals(searchstr.toString())) {

                        SearchArray.add(strvalue);

                        displaylist();

                    } else {
                        displaylist();
                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

then add your custom search method to your `TextWatcher`

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            setsearcharray(s);
        }

    };
```

Dont forget to add `setarray(); displaylist();` to your `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method to first time generating the list like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lead_layout);

        setarray();

        displaylist();
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Great but isn't this a little slow for databases with lots of entries?