# Error while using filtering on android listview?

Tags: android, android-listview, filtering

I am trying to add filtering to my listview in android application.Its not working properly as gives me following exception after writing 3-4 alphabets in my search box.

```
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at com.sphinx.indianrailways.adapters.CityAdapter.getView(CityAdapter.java:57)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1332)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
07-02 12:14:48.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22028):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
```

MY code for filtering looks like this :

```
filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // When user changed the Text by typing in search box
                adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };

        citySearchBox.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
```

My StationAdapter.java code is:

```
    public class CityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<City> {
    ArrayList<City> cityLists = new ArrayList<City>();
    private Context context;
    public String noInternet = "No network connectivity.Try again later.";
    City city= null;

    public CityAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<City> cityLists) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, cityLists);
        this.context = context;
        this.cityLists = cityLists;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView cityCode;
        protected TextView cityName;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cityLists.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.single_city_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.cityCode = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.cityCode);
            holder.cityName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.cityName);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        city= getItem(position);

        holder.cityCode.setText(city.getCityCode());
        holder.cityName.setText(city.getCityName());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I know arraylist might be having 1 element at that time and its trying to access it through list[1] which will raise nullpointerexception.But what do I need to change in my code to solve this issue.

Comment: Please show `CityAdapter` implementation

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah I have added CityAdapter code.Please help

Comment: I don't see you using city variable anywhere inside your Adapter, why the line `city= getItem(position);`

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah I am using it in getView() method of the adpater.Please see the code again.

Comment: I can see that. My question is why are you using it (you are not assigning it to anything else in the Adapter after the line `city= getItem(position);`) ?!! This is where your problem is, so if you are not using it remove it

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah I have edited the code which is not using the city object,please check it and help me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32803/discussion-between-user818455-and-mohamed-abdallah)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After our discussion, I think the problem is in the line :

```
 @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cityLists.size();
    }
```

This makes the Adapter think its size is larger than normal (since its size is fixed and not changed after you filter) and cannot get the item that is our of its bounds when `getView()` (`city= getItem(position);`) is being called.

You should  implement the `Filterable` interface (`getFilter()`) as in questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780289/filtering-listview-with-custom-object-adapter) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678163/list-filter-custom-adapter-dont-give-result) and this [example](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/app/LauncherActivity.java.shtml). This will update the `cityLists` Array each time `getFilter()` is called, and its size will be returned normally and also will update the Adapter (`notifyDataSetChanged()`)

**Edit**

An alternative is to remove your `getCount()` (let the super method take effect). This will update the size each time filter is applied instead of returning `cityLists.size()` which is fixed and will let the Adapter thinks that its size is larger than the data it has. Basically, you either implement `getCount()` as you did and in addition add `getFilter()` to change `cityLists` size each time it is filtered, Or, let the system handle both (do not implement `getFilter()` nor `getCount()`)

Comment: Thanks @Mohamed for explaination