# Filtering search results by a string in Android

Tags: android, search, android-listview

I want to have a search field in which I can put what I want to search for. I already have this implementation.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // List view
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;


    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Listview Data
        String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                                "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
                                "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

But it only returns the result if the search field starts with the same char sequence. As an example, if I write "Galaxy Note", it does not return any result, even though there is an element called "Samsung Galaxy Note 800"

Comment: You should write your own getFilter() function [like that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780289/filtering-listview-with-custom-object-adapter)

Comment: It is just a sugestion but I would try to filter for %galaxy note%. With a little bit luck it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write your own filter class like that and use it in getFilter() function of baseAdapter.

```
private class yourFilter extends Filter
{

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
        ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> p = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String product : products){
               p.add(product);
            }
        if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++)
            {
                String product = p.get(i);
                if(product.toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                    f.add(product);
            }
            result.count = f.size();
            result.values = f;
        }
        else
        {              
             result.values = p;
             result.count = p.size();                
        }
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        yourFilteredData = (ArrayList<String>)results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that your ListView contains plain string values then the simplest way to achieve this is to use this:

```
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

After initializing the lv variable. How ever if your ListView contains complex (non-primitive) data types, this method won't work as intended. Refer to [Google's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3atextFilterEnabled) for assistance.