# Listview with filter

Tags: android

i am trying to filter the listview using edit text at the top but it providing null pointer exception in the adapter2.filter(text) of add text changed listener . please provide me some suggestion`

Here is my edit text`

```
friendsList.setAdapter(new FriendListAdapter(this));

    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String text = search.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            System.out.println("test=="+text);
            adapter2.filter(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    });
```

Here is my adapter

```
public class FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    FriendsList friendsList;
    Context context;
    ViewHolder holder;
    private boolean userSelected = false;
    private RadioButton mCurrentlyCheckedRB;

    private int mResourceId = 0;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater; 
    private RadioButton mSelectedRB;
    private int mSelectedPosition = -1;

    public FriendListAdapter(FriendsList friendsList) {
        this.friendsList = friendsList;
        if (Utility.model == null) {
            Utility.model = new FriendsGetProfilePics();
        }
        Utility.model.setListener(this);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(friendsList.getBaseContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return jsonArray.length();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewgroup) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        Model model = (Model) getItem(position);
        try {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        View hView = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            hView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_item, null);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.profile_pic = (ImageView) hView
                    .findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
            holder.name = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.info = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.info);
            holder.radiobt = (RadioButton) hView.findViewById(R.id.radio);
            hView.setTag(holder);
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) hView.getTag();
        if (position == getCount() - 1 && userSelected == false) {
            holder.radiobt.setChecked(true);
            mCurrentlyCheckedRB = holder.radiobt;
        } else {
            holder.radiobt.setChecked(false);
        }

        holder.radiobt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                if((position != mSelectedPosition && mSelectedRB != null)){
                    mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
                }

                mSelectedPosition = position;
                mSelectedRB = (RadioButton)v;


                System.out.println("onItemClick ");
                try {

                    if (graph_or_fql.equals("graph")) {

                        System.out.println("in if loop ");
                        friendId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getLong("id");
                        image = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("picture");
                        // sb.append(friendId).append(",");
                        freind_id = String.valueOf(friendId);

                    } else {

                        System.out.println("in else loop ");
                        friendId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getLong("uid");
                        image = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString(
                                "pic_square");
                        // sb.append(friendId).append(",");
                        freind_id = String.valueOf(friendId);
                    }
                    check = true;
                    name = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("name");

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Selected : " + name,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    e.getMessage();
                }



            }
        });


        if(mSelectedPosition != position){
            holder.radiobt.setChecked(false);
        }else{
            holder.radiobt.setChecked(true);
            if(mSelectedRB != null && holder.radiobt != mSelectedRB){
                mSelectedRB = holder.radiobt;
            }
        }

    try {
            if (graph_or_fql.equals("graph")) {
                holder.profile_pic.setImageBitmap(Utility.model.getImage(
                        jsonObject.getString("id"),
                        jsonObject.getString("picture")));
            } else {
                holder.profile_pic.setImageBitmap(Utility.model.getImage(
                        jsonObject.getString("uid"),
                        jsonObject.getString("pic_square")));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder.name.setText("");
        }
        try {
            holder.name.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder.name.setText("");
        }
        try {
            if (graph_or_fql.equals("graph")) {
                holder.info.setText(jsonObject.getJSONObject("location")
                        .getString("name"));
            } else {
                JSONObject location = jsonObject
                        .getJSONObject("current_location");
                holder.info.setText(location.getString("city") + ", "
                        + location.getString("state"));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder.info.setText("");
        }
        return hView;

    }


    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        System.out.println("in adapter filter");
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        System.out.println("1");
        rowitems.clear();
        System.out.println("2");

        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println("3");
            rowitems.addAll(listData);
        } else {
            for (Model wp : listData) {
                if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    rowitems.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView profile_pic;
        TextView name;
        TextView info;
        // CheckBox check;
        RadioButton radiobt;
    }       
}
```

Here is my main activity

```
public class FriendsList extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

private Handler mHandler;
public static Long friendId;
public static String name = "";
protected ListView friendsList;
protected static JSONArray jsonArray;
protected String graph_or_fql;
public Button bt;
public static String image = "0";
public boolean check = false;
public static String freind_id = "";
public boolean select = false;
public RadioButton radiobtn;    

public ListView friendList; 
private List<Model> rowitems=null;
ArrayList<Model> listData;
    AdapterList adapter;
    EditText search;

FriendListAdapter adapter2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mHandler = new Handler();
    setContentView(R.layout.friends_list);
    //radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.com_facebook_picker_done_button);
    radiobtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio);

    search=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText100);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String apiResponse = extras.getString("API_RESPONSE");
    graph_or_fql = extras.getString("METHOD");
    try {
        if (graph_or_fql.equals("graph")) {
            jsonArray = new JSONObject(apiResponse).getJSONArray("data");
        } else {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(apiResponse);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
        return;
    }
    friendsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friends_list);

//  friendsList.setAdapter(new FriendListAdapter(this));

    adapter2=new FriendListAdapter(this);
    friendsList.setAdapter(adapter2);

    friendsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              adapter2.getFilter().filter(arg0.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

i am passing the facebook friend list to the listview.please provide some suggestion
Thanks in advance

Comment: i think your problem is with `rowitems` in Filter Class, can you able to print `1`?

Comment: No its not comming to the getfilter method at all

Comment: what you set for `adapter2`

Comment: post your updated code and error log

Comment: refer it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780289/filtering-listview-with-custom-object-adapter and override `filter` method within your `FriendListAdapter`

Comment: i think its better if you use autocompletetextview

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android

Answer (score 1):

For filter the listview using edit text at the top .
I used this code.
Make one list called `searchResults` than in `onTextChanged` method of `edittext` simply do this-

```
String searchString = `your edittext object`.getText().toString();
int textLength = searchString.length();
searchResults.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < `your main list of items`.size(); i++) {
String name = `your main list of items`.get(i).get("`your key`").toString();
System.out.println(" name " + name);
if (textLength <= title.length()) {
// compare the String in EditText with Names in the
// ArrayList
if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(name.substring(0, textLength))) {
    searchResults.add(`your main list of items`.get(i));
    System.out.println("the array list is "+ `your main list of items`.get(i));
    mAdapter = new Adapter(this, searchResults);
    `your ListView object`.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
     }
  }
  if (searchResults.isEmpty()) {
  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Items Matched",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
  toast.show();
  mAdapter = new Adapter(this, searchResults);
    `your ListView object`.setAdapter(mAdapter);
 }
  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and on `setOnItemClickListener` just check `searchResults.isEmpty()` if true than use your `your main list of items` and if false than use `searchResults` list.
May be it will help you.try this.

Answer (score 0):

change your filter with following code:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    //Log.d("in filter", "yes");
    return new Filter() {
          @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
```

and set your list in this function and after set your list :

```
    oReturn.values = YourList;
```

and finall

```
    return oReturn;
```

and in Your `search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher())` just in `onTextChanged` add following line:

```
    adapter2.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
```

Comment: its not at all calling the filter method,it showing NPE in addtext changed listener

Comment: what is the `adapter2`? is this first adapter that you show data or is new adapter?

Comment: adapter 2 is object for this : FriendListAdapter

Comment: I know but i want know is it first adapter that you show data or create new adapter? because you must worked with first adapter.

Comment: first adapter that you create and show your list, are you using `adapter2`? i think that must be in onCreat() method

Comment: No i am having only one adapter,i just named it as adapter 2 thats it,

Comment: Hi,its not filtering the list and its ot showing NPE also,what can i do

Comment: so how you know that is NPE?

Comment: before it says NPE once i changed the code as per u said it not showing NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
adapter2=new FriendListAdapter(this);
friendsList.setAdapter(adapter2);
```