# Best practice to use AsyncTask in autocomplete?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am using Async task to populate auto-complete suggestions from server.

**Problem:**
when user types and removes the text in edittext so many times.
lets say he typed:  cofee > cof > coffee >coffee late .... etc for so many times.
for each text changed after 3 keyword(threshold) i am initializing an asynctask and ask for result.
so in current scenario i have so many threads running in background. so some of my latest async threads are waiting for there chance.
Whole this make my app very slow.

What can I do to tackle this problem?

Comment: you should start a timer of 1 or 2 sec after everytime user will enter three later. Then start the async task

Comment: but that will stop the latest thread to execute even

Comment: i tried to cancel the the current task and execute again it gives me :
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible to load entire data from server at beginning...then you can avoid calling asynctask repeatedly and fetching the data from server. This will improve performance of you app. If data displayed in Listview is String, following link show how to filter it:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

And if custom object is used in ListView adapter, try:

[Filtering ListView with custom (object) adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780289/filtering-listview-with-custom-object-adapter)

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: data is very large and dynamic. can't load at first time.

Answer (score 0):

You should cancel the current task before issuing a new one. Use `AsyncTask#cancel(true)` for that and make sure that the execution of the task can be quickly stopped. This means correct handling of interruption and frequent checking whether the task was cancelled in the body of `AsyncTask#doInBackground`.

And you cannot execute again the AsyncTask you have cancelled. You have to create a new one. (Trying to execute it again leads to IllegalStateExceptions)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by **cancelling** the task each time you **change the text** (if it is still running).

You need to define your request once outside the listener(private for the class), and then start your listener function by (if your request is not finished, then cancel it).

define your request  out side the function

```
private YourSearchTaskClass YourTaskReq = new YourSearchTaskClass();
```

then start your addTextChangeListener/afterTextChanged by this

```
if (YourTaskReq.getStatus()!= AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
   YourTaskAvReq.cancel(false);

YourTaskReq= new YourSearchTaskClass(keyword);
```