# Custom array adapter filter error

Tags: android, android-listview, filter

I added search event to my list view. but it return java.lang.NullPointerException.

I used [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780289/filtering-listview-with-custom-object-adapter?rq=1) as example.

This is my activity class code.

```
public void ListDrwaer() {  
        listData = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(strJson1);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("restaurants");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                restName = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
                String type = jsonChildNode.optString("type");

                if(type.equals("restaurant")){
                    listData.add(restName);

                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error..." + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if(restName!=null){
            adapter = new FevListAdapter(Restaurant_List.this,listData);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            searchTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Restaurant_List.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });

             list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {

                        TextView textView = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.fav_list);
                        String text = textView.getText().toString(); 
                        Intent newActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),Fav_Tabs.class);  
                          newActivity.putExtra("Rest_name", text);
                          startActivity(newActivity);

                    }
                });
        }
        else{

            text.setText("No data found...");
        }   
    }
```

This is my adapter class.

```
public class FevListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

    private Context context;
    List<String> listData;

    private List<String> list;
    public FevListAdapter(Context convertView, List<String> listData){

        this.context = convertView;
        this.listData = listData;
        //Edited
        //this.list.addAll(listData);

    }
.............................

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final String text = listData.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.fev_rest_list, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.fav_list);
        lblListHeader.setText(text);
        return convertView;
    }


     @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {

            Filter filter = new Filter() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                    list = (List<String>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                    ArrayList<String> FilteredArrayNames = new ArrayList<String>();

                    // perform your search here using the searchConstraint String.

                    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        String dataNames = list.get(i);
                        if (dataNames.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()))  {
                            FilteredArrayNames.add(dataNames);
                        }
                    }

                    results.count = FilteredArrayNames.size();
                    results.values = FilteredArrayNames;
                    Log.e("VALUES", results.values.toString());

                    return results;
                }
            };

            return filter;
        }
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Edited

This is my logcat error

```
02-10 22:11:45.661: E/AndroidRuntime(28229): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 22:11:45.661: E/AndroidRuntime(28229): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-10 22:11:45.661: E/AndroidRuntime(28229):    at com.example.rp.FevListAdapter.<init>(FevListAdapter.java:28)
02-10 22:11:45.661: E/AndroidRuntime(28229):    at com.example.rp.Restaurant_List.ListDrwaer(Restaurant_List.java:224)
02-10 22:11:45.661: E/AndroidRuntime(28229):    at com.example.rp.Restaurant_List$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(Restaurant_List.java:175)
02-10 22:11:45.661: E/AndroidRuntime(28229):    at com.example.rp.Restaurant_List$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(Restaurant_List.java:1)
02-10 22:11:45.661: E/AndroidRuntime(28229):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-10 22:11:45.661: E/AndroidRuntime(28229):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-10 22:11:45.661: E/AndroidRuntime(28229):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-10 22:11:45.661: E/AndroidRuntime(28229):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-10 22:11:45.661: E/AndroidRuntime(28229):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-10 22:11:45.661: E/AndroidRuntime(28229):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
02-10 22:11:45.661: E/AndroidRuntime(28229):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 22:11:45.661: E/AndroidRuntime(28229):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-10 22:11:45.661: E/AndroidRuntime(28229):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-10 22:11:45.661: E/AndroidRuntime(28229):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-10 22:11:45.661: E/AndroidRuntime(28229):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If you could provide the logcat for this that will help find what line the error occurred.

Comment: what is your jsonArray? are you sure about the Restaurants and Restaurant spelling difference

Comment: @user2450263 I successfully loaded data. it return data correctly.i cant add search to this listview. error with the filter i think.

Comment: What is line no.28 in FevListAdapter

Comment: this.list.addAll(listData);

Comment: post your json content, listData is empty then

Comment: If i remove that line it load data to listview otherwise not load data

Comment: Yes! as i just saw that it is not being used, why do you want to keep it then?!

Comment: @user2450263 i remove that.but still it not working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47199/discussion-between-anuruddhika-and-user2450263)