# Adapter update from afterTextChanged()

Tags: android, android-adapter, autocompletetextview

The problem is I cant update `adapter` after it was set. For first character it works fine, but if I want to change it `adapter` keeps viewing the same suggests. How can I update `adapter`?
Here is my code.

```
public class UzActivity extends Activity  {

private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "HttpExample";
List<String> responseList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_uz);
    responseList = new ArrayList<String>();

    final String url = "http://booking.uz.gov.ua/purchase/station/";

    final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, responseList);


    textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if (s.length()>0 && responseList.isEmpty()){

                try {
                    new FetchStationTask().execute(url + URLEncoder.encode(s.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                textView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            else if(s.length()==0){
                responseList.clear();
            }
        }
    });
}



private class FetchStationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            return new UzFetcher().getUrlString(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            StationResponse st = objectMapper.readValue(result, StationResponse.class);
            for (int i = 0; i<st.mStations.size(); i++){
                    responseList.add(st.mStations.get(i).getTitle());
            }


            Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, responseList.get(0));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, result);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)? `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` instead of `textView.setAdapter(adapter)`.

also you have line `if (s.length()>0 && responseList.isEmpty())` but when you put first digit probably adapter isn't empty and also second condition `if(s.length()==0)` is false

Comment: Yes I tried, but its not working. Maybe I should setup adater in asynctask?

Comment: you should set up your adapter in `onPostExecute` with  `notifyDataSetChanged` below whole `try..catch`. you may also use filtering if it matches your purposes [(example here)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780289/filtering-listview-with-custom-object-adapter)

Answer (score 1):

- Please notify adapter in onPostExecute(String result){} method.

> ```
> onPostExecute(String result){
>     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
> }
> ```