# Filter custom adapter/listview with custom object

Tags: android, listview, filter, adapter

I have custom object and adapter which use it. I would like to use filter for adapter, but default implementation doesn´t work. How to setup custom filter in adapter?

```
public class CustomObject {

public String variable1;
public String variable2;
public String variable3;

public CustomObject(String variable1, String variable2, String variable3) {
    super();

    this.variable1 = variable1;
    this.variable2 = variable2;
    this.variable3 = variable3;
    }
}
```

---

In Activity I have adapter:

```
CustomObject data[] = new CustomObject [size];
AdapterContact adapter = new AdapterContact(context, R.layout.row, data);
ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.getFilter().filter("keyword");
```

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0) generic adapter

Comment: Could you advice me how? I checked a some implementations, but all of them used ArrayList, not Array and I do not uderstand, how to do same for array.

Comment: here you have a sample implementation: http://pastebin.com/1UwqrHxv

Comment: No, I checked that, but still not clear to me :( I found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780289/filtering-listview-with-custom-object-adapter?rq=1), but it applies to ArrayList.

Comment: Yes, that I checked and didn´t understand :( This means I have to rewrite adapter and I do not understand, how this will filter listview.