# Issues getting search data in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-package-managers, android-search

I have implemented filterable in customadapter class and i am able to search through listview ,but when i empty my searchbox my list still show the last search app and not with whole app list.

mainactivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
 List<ApplicationInfo> appList;
 ListAdapter listAdapter;
 PackageManager packageManager;
 Process suProcess;
 DataOutputStream os;
 ApplicationInfo info;
 EditText search;
 ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    packageManager = getPackageManager();
    new LoadApplication().execute();

    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            listAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
 }
 }
```

I have added my Filter Class.

```
private class ListFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            results.values = applist;
            results.count = applist.size();
        } else {
            ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> info = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();

            for (ApplicationInfo c : applist) {
                if (c.loadLabel(packageManager).toString().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                    info.add(c);
                }
            }
            results.values = info;
            results.count = info.size();
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        if (results.count == 0) {
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        } else {
            applist = (List<ApplicationInfo>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And overrided getFilter() method.

```
 public Filter getFilter() {

    if (filter == null)
    {
        filter=new ListFilter();
    }
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: as i am new to this...can u please show me some startup codes

Answer (score 1):

For Adding Searching you need to add Filter  like below code:

```
 private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<String> list = originalData;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

            String filterableString ;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

follow below link and Add filter in your Adapter :

[Filtering ListView with custom (object) adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780289/filtering-listview-with-custom-object-adapter)

Comment: i have been hearing about this method alot...but stucked on how to implement it ...consider me as newbie in this and help

Comment: follow link which have added above .

Comment: thanx chetan ,,, now i can search but when i empty my searchbox i dnt get whole list filled ,it still shows the last search result.