# ListView baseadapter class implement TextWatcher

Tags: java, android, baseadapter, textwatcher

i have an baseadapter custom listview and edittext. I want to get data from edittext and change values of all the listview items with text watcher on text change. when i enter a new value text start changing instead of after i finish entering values.
im working in fragment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering ListView with custom (object) adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780289/filtering-listview-with-custom-object-adapter)

Comment: can u give me some code that can help me.
in above example they are adding search view to custom adapter. how can i implement this to change the values in listview everytime i enter some number in edittext. :)

Answer (score 0):

You Try [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/)
 Example and also search in google "listview Filter" you will get so many examples